# EnumHelper.GetSelectList in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I simply want to use the above subject to populate a list of predefined Enum values in a dropdownlist, but am running up against syntactical issues.

For example, if I just want to populate a dropdownlist (not associated with any enums, the following code will suffice):

```
List<CustomerDDL> customerList = await db.GetCustomerDDLAsync();
            ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(customerList, "CustomerID", "Email", project.CustomerID);
```

However, if I want to populate a dropdownlist consisting of enum values, the following syntax doesn't work. I get a design time compiler error of:

```
'YeagerTechDB.Enums.CategoryTypeEnum' is a 'type', but used like a 'variable'.
```

I know what the error implies, but simply do not know how to syntactically construct the SelectList.

I have the following line trying to create it which is giving me the error. Note that this code is inside my **controller** in order to select the selected value.

```
ViewData["Categories"] = new CategoriesDDL();
            List<CategoriesDDL> categoryList = EnumHelper.GetSelectList(ViewData.ModelMetadata, (System.Enum)CategoryTypeEnum);
ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(categoryList, "CategoryID", "CategoryDescription", project.CategoryID);
```

My Enum model is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace YeagerTechDB.Enums
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public enum CategoryTypeEnum : short
    {
        [EnumMember]
        [Display(Name = "Medical")]
        Medical = 9,
        [EnumMember]
        [Display(Name = "Financial")]
        Financial = 10,
        [EnumMember]
        [Display(Name = "Logistics")]
        Logistics = 11,
        [EnumMember]
        [Display(Name = "Accounting")]
        Accounting = 12
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out with the exact syntax I need for the SelectList?

Comment: Post your Model? `EnumHelper.GetSelectList` requires that the second argument is the enum value, it will use this value to pre-select it in the dropdown list. `EnumHelper.GetSelectList(ViewData.ModelMetadata, Model.SelectedEnumValue)`

Comment: OK, I get the use of it now.... Guess I'll have to put a method in my DB layer to retrieve the values out of the table then.

Comment: You could probably just do: `EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(CategoryTypeEnum))`

Comment: Tried it... didn't work... I just got the data from the db....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 5, you can try to use `EnumDropDownListFor`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: This is inside my Controller; not my View. I simply need to select the value the user selected in the Enum dropdownlist (on the view) for the Create method in my Controller.

Comment: Guess I'll have to put a method in my DB layer to retrieve the values out of the table then.